# Filters do not work when there are multiple (one works)

Tags: posts, functions, wp-query, categories, filters

I have this functions code:

```
function my_query($query)
{
    if (is_post_type_archive('mycustomposttype')) {
        $orderby = sanitize_text_field(get_query_var('orderby'));
        $orderby2 = sanitize_text_field(get_query_var('orderby2'));
        $tax_query = array();
        $tax_query2 = array();
        
        if ($orderby !== 'all') {
            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $orderby,
            );
        }
        if ($orderby2 !== 'all2') {
            $tax_query2[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $orderby2,
            );
        }
        $query->set('tax_query', array_merge($tax_query, $tax_query2));
    }
}
```

And I have these filters:

```
<form method='GET' id="filter-form">

    <select name='orderby' id='orderby' onchange="document.getElementById('filter-form').submit()">
        <option value="all" selected>All</option>
        <?php
            $terms = get_terms([
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'hide_empty' => 'false',
            ]);
            foreach ($terms as $term) :
        ?>

        <option value='<?php echo $term->slug; ?>' <?php echo selected(sanitize_text_field($_GET['orderby']), $term->slug); ?>><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <select name='orderby2' id='orderby2' onchange="document.getElementById('filter-form').submit()">
        <option value="all2" selected>All2</option>
        <?php
            $terms2 = get_terms([
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'hide_empty' => 'false',
            ]);
            foreach ($terms2 as $term2) :
        ?>
        <option value='<?php echo $term2->slug; ?>' <?php echo selected(sanitize_text_field($_GET['orderby2']), $term2->slug); ?>><?php echo $term2->name; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

My goal: make sure both filters work, independently from each other (or at least: that they both work properly). Currently, when I add the second select as I did in the code, the code fails. Both filters fail. If I use only one select filter, it works.. but I need them both in separate dropdowns.

How can I achieve that? Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed your filter function is using [`get_query_var()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) which automatically parses URL/form parameters from the superglobals `$_GET` and `$_POST`, but only if the parameters are registered as **public** query vars.

Were you aware of that, and have you registered the `orderby2` parameter as a *public query var*?

Because in my case (WordPress v6.1.1), the 2nd filter failed because `orderby2` wasn't a registered query var, hence the value was always *empty*:

```php
$orderby2 = sanitize_text_field(get_query_var('orderby2'));
```

So try registering it as query var like so, which uses [`query_vars`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_vars/):

```php
function myplugin_query_vars( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'orderby2';
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'myplugin_query_vars' );
```

<sub>Note: I didn't register `orderby` because it is one of the many [reserved terms in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms), and WordPress automatically registers it as a query var.</sub>

Or you could instead just use `$_GET['orderby2']` to get the value:

```php
$orderby2 = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['orderby2'] ?? 'all2' );
```

Comment: This seems to be working! Just a quick question, because that functionality seems to be changed now: how can I show all posts on initial page load? It was like that, but after I merged your snippet, it is not showing anything. Any chance you can help?

Comment: Try using `if ($orderby && $orderby !== 'all')` and `if ($orderby2 && $orderby2 !== 'all2')` instead of those in your post/question. I.e. Check if the query var is not empty before adding items to the tax query arrays

Comment: Incredible! It works.  Thank you so much, @Sally!